# Checking if a website is responsive with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a code that check if a certain page have responsive design, and how do I intend to do this?

Simple, basically when a website is responsive, all its elements like divs, spans, footers, headers, sections and so on... usually have the same screen width or do not usually exceed that.

For example, if we open a website that is responsive on a mobile device (eg Iphone 6, which has 375x667), and we analyze all HTML elements (`div`, `span`, `header`, `section`, `footer`), we will see that they all do not exceed width of 375.

And what's my idea? Create a Code with Puppeteer That enter in a website, simulate a mobile device (iPhone 6), grab all the HTML elements and check if the width of each of them is larger than the screen width of the iphone 6 (375 pixels).

For this I try the following code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('http://stackoverflow.com/my-example.html');
await await page.emulate(devices['iPhone 6']);

const allstyles = await page.$$('table');

await browser.close();
console.log(allstyles);
```

In `http://stackoverflow.com/my-example.html` I have many tables and one of them has 600px of width (more than 375px of iPhone 6):

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
....
```

How can I use Puppeteer to get the width of all elements and check if width is more than 375px ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question: You can do this by using [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args). The following code queries all elements in the page, gets their width, filters them so that only the elements with a width greater than `375` stay and then checks if there is at least one element remaining.

**Code**

```js
const await page.evaluate(() =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll('*')]
  .map(el => el.offsetWidth)
  .filter(width => width > 375)
  .length > 0;
);
```

However, you should consider if you might want to prefer just checking if there is a scrollbar visible, for example by comparing `document.body.offsetWidth` and `window.innerWidth`. Right now, there might be elements whose width is greater than your page, but the page might still be responsible as this could be hidden in a `overflow:hidden` container.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I'm having some problem to implement your solution in my code, can you post the full code ?

Comment: is it an expensive transaction ?